# solving ODE on microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, differential-equations, ode

I would like to solve two ODE first order on microcontroller. It has to be evaluated every 100ms

```
x'=-k_{1}\cdot (x-x_{ref})\cdot e^{-b\cdot ((x-x_{obs})^{2}+(y-y_{obs})^{2})}
y'=-k_{1}\cdot (y-y_{ref})\cdot e^{-b\cdot ((x-x_{obs})^{2}+(y-y_{obs})^{2})}
```

Basically i thought of using euler integration (Runge-Kute I)

```
y(k+1)=y(k)+f(k,y(k))*dT
```

I expect error to be < 0.001. How do i determine how many iterations i should run until i hit that error rate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `x` and `y`, as well as `x_{ref}`, `y_{ref}`, `x_{obs}`, `y_{obs}` are time dependent. This limits the number of ODE solver you can use. So it can be only the Euler method and a Runge-Kutta method of 2 order (I forgot the name), which evaluate the r.h.s of you ODE only at the time points `x(t)`, `x(t+dT)´,`x(t+2dT)`,...

You can use classical step size control with these two methods. That is you make one with step with the Euler method and one step with the RK-II method. The difference between these two steps is an indicator for the error and can be used for classical step size control. Have a look at the Numerical Recipes for more details.

Comment: Only `x` and `y` are time dependant. Those others are constant values. I will try with RK-2. What i dont understand is following: im using calculated x and y every 100ms, at that point in time i set constants x_ref, x_obs. So every 100ms i set boundary for ODE as x(0) = previous cycle value ? and run the ODE for dT=0.1 ?

Comment: Sure, that is absolutely common. In principle the Runge-Kutta methods work iteratively and map a give x(t) to a x(t+dT). This one is then mapped to x(t+2dT) and so...

Comment: I tried Euler method in `Matlab` and it gives good enough result. So i will go with Euler implementation on microcontroller. Thanks for the tips.